# Facebook app how many test users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-test-users

This question, or very similar has been asked before - but I think FB has changed their developer console since.

I'm developing an FB app and would like to test it internally with staff - around 500-1000 is the intention.

Is there a limit to how any real test users I can add within the Roles section in the developer console?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t find a limit mentioned anywhere in the docs, but that does not necessarily not mean there isn’t any.

Comment: yea thats what i'm worried about - I'd hate to send out a thousand invites only to find out that the limit is 10... :)

Comment: you need to add them to the roles anyway before sending invites...

Comment: ah we're actually going to do it kind of backwards... we don't know the FB ID's of the testers, so we'll send out an invite email to staff, then take them to a landing page asking them to enter their FB details - we'll take those and add them as test users.

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook Test Users documentation section, you're limited to only 2000 test users per application.

> Apps are limited to 2000 Test Users.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/

Comment: Good answer, but instead of adding the relevant information as an image, you should consider adding the text itself.

Comment: Edited, Thanks for the advice, I'm kinda new here.